# Is google still honoring the "max_age" request parameter in requests to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid

According to [OIDC specs](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) when an authentication request contains the `max_age` field

> the ID Token returned MUST include an `auth_time` Claim Value

Starting January 28, we don't see the `auth_time` field returned in the ID Token returned from the google auth api.

Did anything changed on the Google side as far as honoring that flag is concerned?

Thank you!